# How to set a proxy for the azure-cli command line tool?

Tags: azure

I'm behind a corporate firewall and cannot connect using the command line interface, which probably doesn't get proxy information from the system configuration, but I cannot find a way to set the correct options.

Answer (score 31):

The environment variables mentioned in the other answer are part of the solution, so you do need to set them by running these commands before `az login`. Note that (in my case, at least) both URLs start with http, not https.

In PowerShell:

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY="http://my-proxy-details"
$env:HTTPS_PROXY="http://my-proxy-details"
```

In cmd:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY http://my-proxy-details
SET HTTPS_PROXY http://my-proxy-details
```

Or, to set them permanently:

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://my-proxy-details", "Machine")`

`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://my-proxy-details", "Machine")`

If that fixes it for you, you can stop reading here. If not, and you see a certificate error, the extra step is to find the Azure CLI's private Python installation, and add your root certificate to its `cacert.pem` files. While Python itself uses the Windows certificate store, some packages (notably certifi) do not.

You will need your proxy's root certificate in PEM format - that is, as base64 text rather than as a binary. It may well have the `.cer` extension.

Find the site-packages folder inside Azure CLI's program folder. For me, it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages`. Search it for files named `cacert.pem`. I found three of them. Copy the contents of your certificate and paste it at the bottom of each of these files. Save them and try again.

Comment: on `win10` with `az cli > 3.10` I found the `cascert.pem` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\Lib\site-packages\certifi`

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY environment variables to set a proxy.

Comment: Now I get an error... SSL Certificate untrusted... is there a way also to create something like NPM strict-ssl property?

Comment: Today, unfortunately, you can achieve it only through code. Try setting strictSSL = false in your client object.

Comment: In what way does setting env variables change anything? Tried it: does not work at all.

Comment: Set AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1 to avoid SSL issues when using a SSL-intercepting HTTP proxy

Answer (score 2):

In CMD

You need add "=" when set environment variables:

```
SET HTTP_PROXY=http://my-proxy-details
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://my-proxy-details
```

In PowerShell:

```
$env:HTTP_PROXY="http://my-proxy-details"
$env:HTTPS_PROXY="http://my-proxy-details"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do this from the Windows Settings GUI.

Go to the Proxy Settings page in Windows Settings. Make sure the "Use a proxy server" is toggled on, enter your proxy address and port, hit Save, relaunch Powershell, and the CLI should connect properly.

[image]