# Can't list HDInsight clusters

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, cortana-intelligence

I'm trying to use the [azure command-line interface](http://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/).
I imported the manifest file and am able to run `azure hdinsight -h` and `azure account list` (which gives me the good credentials).

However, I'm unable to list my HDInsight clusters with

```
azure hdinsight cluster list
```

This returns me the following error :

```
- Getting HDInsight serverserror:   tunneling socket could not be established, cause=1500:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:766:

info:    Error information has been recorded to azure.err
error:   hdinsight cluster list command failed
```

I get a similar error message when doing `azure hdinsight account storage create storagename`

Did I miss a step in the installation or is there something wrong going on ? I'm working behind a proxy and got `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` well set.

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in this article: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-administer-use-command-line/

Comment: @JonathanGao I did, see the edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set a proxy for the azure-cli command line tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500613/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-the-azure-cli-command-line-tool)

Answer (score 0):

In order to proceed ahead with the project, you could also launch the Powershell from the portal itself and execute the PowerShell commandlet from there. (It is called CloudShell in Azure, click this highlighted icon [image] I just launched the PowerShell windows from portal and executed "azure hdinsight cluster list" and it returned me the list of my clusters. 
more details about the Azure Powershell at :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powershell-comes-to-azure-cloud-shell/ 
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart-powershell