# Azure CLI Rest issue with encoding (German Umlauts)

Tags: json, azure, powershell, rest, encoding

I am using the `az rest` command to create users inside Azure API Management and face an issue with usernames that contain german **umlauts** (like ä, ö, ü). The script will create the user but the name contain invalid characters. Here an example:

[image]

This is how I create the user. I do write the user in a file due to some PowerShell / AZ issues with double quotes and pass it to the **az cli** :

```
@{
    properties = @{
      confirmation = "invite"
      firstName    = "Max"
      lastName     = "Müstermann"
      email        = "max.mustermann@stackoverflow.com"
      appType      = "developerPortal"
    }
  } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File $tmpFile -Encoding UTF8
```

This is how I pass the file to the cli:

```
az rest --method put --uri $uri --body @$tmpFile
```

The file itself looks fine:
[image]

I already tried to add a header for `charset=utf-8` - but it doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the issue with double quotes? It sounds like it might be better to try to fix that, rather than solve the problem with the workaround...

Comment: @mclayton This is a known PowerShell issue (read more [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md#double-quotes--are-lost)) . The best fix for that is basically what you see here (replacing the quotes with escaped double quotes twice is worse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Horrible Workaround**

I've reproduced your issue here, and so far the only way I've got it to work is to replace the `ü` with a json unicode escape sequence:

```bsh
$data = @{
    properties = @{
      confirmation = "invite"
      firstName    = "Max"
      lastName     = "Müstermann"
      email        = "max.mustermann@example.org"
      appType      = "developerPortal"
    }
}
$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress;
#             vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
$json = $json.Replace("ü", "\u00FC"); # <----- replace ü with escape sequence
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Set-Content -Path $tmpfile -Value $json;

$requestUri = "https://management.azure.com/" +
                  "subscriptions/$subscriptionId/" +
                  "resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/" +
                  "providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/" +
                  "service/$serviceName/" +
                  "users/$username" +
                  "?api-version=2019-12-01";

az rest --method put --uri $requestUri --body @$tmpFile
```

which gives:

[image]

I know that's not a very satisfying solution though because it doesn't solve the general case of all non-ascii characters, and you're hacking around with the converted json which might break things in weird edge cases.

One extreme option might be to write your own json serializer that escapes the appropriate characters - I'm not saying that's a good idea, but it would potentially work. If you think about going down that route here's a raw PowerShell serializer I wrote a while ago for a very niche use case that you could use as a starting point and tweak the string serialization code to escape the appropriate characters - [ConvertTo-OctopusJson.ps1](https://github.com/ASOS/OctopusStepTemplateCi/blob/master/OctopusStepTemplateCi/Cmdlets/Internal/Octopus/Common/ConvertTo-OctopusJson.ps1)

Hopefully that might be enough to unblock you or at least give you options to think about...

**More Info**

For anyone else investigating this issue, here's a few pointers:

- You can get `az` to send requests via Fiddler if you set the following environment variables:

```
:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500613/how-to-set-a-proxy-for-the-azure-cli-command-line-tool
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://127.0.0.1:8888

:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55463706/ssl-handshake-error-with-some-azure-cli-commands
set ADAL_PYTHON_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
set AZURE_CLI_DISABLE_CONNECTION_VERIFICATION=1
```

- It looks like the `--body @$tmpfile` parameter *doesn't* send the file as a binary blob. Instead, it reads the file as text and re-encodes it as ISO-8859-1 (the default encoding for HTTP). For example, if the file is UTF8-encoded with `ü` represented as `C3 BC`:

[image]

the file content still gets converted to in ISO-8859-1 encoding with `ü` represented as `FC` when `az` sends the HTTP request:

[image]

- The response comes back as this:

[image]

where `ï¿½` (`EF BF BD`) is the UTF8 representation of the Unicode "[REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm)":

[image]

- My guess is that the client-side is sending he body as ISO-8859-1 but the server-side is treating it as UTF8. The server fails to decode the ISO-8859-1 byte `FC` as `ü`, and replaces it with the "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER" instead, and finally encodes the response as UTF8.

This can be simulated as follows:

```bsh
# client sends request encoded with iso-8859-1
$requestText = "Müstermann";
$iso88591 = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
$requestBytes = $iso88591.GetBytes($requestText);
write-host "iso-8859-1 bytes = '$($requestBytes | % { $_.ToString("X2") })'";
# iso-8859-1 bytes = '4D FC 73 74 65 72 6D 61 6E 6E'

# server decodes request with utf8 instead
$utf8 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;
$mangledText = $utf8.GetString($requestBytes);
write-host "mangled text = '$mangledText'";
# mangled text = 'M�stermann'

# server encodes the response as utf8
$responseBytes = $utf8.GetBytes($mangledText);
write-host "response bytes = '$($responseBytes | % { $_.ToString("X2") })'";
# response bytes = '4D EF BF BD 73 74 65 72 6D 61 6E 6E'
```

which seems to match up with the bytes in the screenshots, so it looks like it *might* be a bug in the Azure API Management API.

Comment: Thanks a lot mclayton, you spent a lot of time on that. I agree - this is not a very satisfying solution but it works. I hope we miss something and someone comes with a more convenient solution, however, I doubt that this will be the case since I am unable to find a better solution :-/. Will accept your answer in a few days if no one else comes with a better solution. Again, thank you mclayton!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was fixed by enabling "*Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support*".

1. Control panel
2. Region
3. Administrative
4. Change system locale...

You'll need to restart your computer for the change to take effect.

[image]

Source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/22616#issuecomment-1147061949